# Use googleapis in ios app

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-api, cllocation

I am implementing an iOS app. I want to use googleapis for fetching user current location.I am not using CLLocation because if user choose 'Don't allow' option in authorization alert, then I won't be able to fetch user current location which is mandatory in my app. I want to know whether apple will reject my app from appstore since I am using googleapis.

Comment: if user denies location and your app is dependent on it, try just showing a screen with valid reason why you want the location and ask user to enable it. Apple wont reject in such case

Comment: Tell them the valid reason first so they don't reject...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apple won't reject your app from app store if you are using google apis.
if you want to use google apis for fetching the user current location,
the google api itself requires to request permission from the user to use location services. 
see this link https://developers.google.com/places/ios-api/current-place
for details.

without requesting permission from the user there is no possibility to fetch user current location using google apis.

Please review the App Store Review Guidelines https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines
before submitting the app to the app store.

In Data Use and Sharing subsection of Privacy Section they have clearly stated that

"Apps cannot use or transmit someone’s personal data without first obtaining their permission and providing access to information about how and where the data will be used."